# График с дополнительными (тремя) осями Y разного масштаба

Tags: c#, график

В программировании новичок, прошу совета у более опытных людей.
Visual Studio C# (net 6.0).
Необходимо отрисовывать график с тремя осями Y (мощность, напор, КПД) с разными масштабами и одной общей осью Х (расход). При этом ось Y КПД высотой ниже, чем остальные две оси Y. Выяснил, что Chart не очень удобен для отрисовки таких графиков, да и не поддерживается в net 6.0.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что бы Вы использовали на моем месте? Буду рад и мануалам к предложенным вариантам. Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По сути все сводится к уменьшению высоты оси КПД. В ZedGraph пока не могу найти такой возможности...

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл. OxyPlot. StartPosition и EndPosition.
https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/axes/index.html